# compose new outlook email with html template

Tags: powershell

My PowerShell script is opening a new compose outlook email window and setting the body to a string that contains HTML, but it is not rendering the HTML. Any ideas how to achieve this?

```
function Prepare_Outlook_email( $subject, $body, $to){
    $ol = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application
    $mail = $ol.CreateItem(0)
    $mail.Subject = $subject
    $mail | Get-Member
    # $mail.IsBodyHTML = $true  ###doesnt work
    # $mail.HTMLBody = $body ###doesnt work the email format is already HTML
    $mail.Body = $body
    $mail.To = $to 
    $inspector = $mail.GetInspector
    $inspector.Activate()
}
```

`$body` is the following string.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Dear firstname,
                    Please visit <a href="www.google.com">here</a>

                    Kind Regards,
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas on how to make the HTML be interpreted. The main problem is that I need to be able to insert hyperlinks. I could live with the HTML not being interpreted if you can tell me a different way to get hyperlinks to work.

I found this old post that suggested using `{ HYPERLINK ="www.google.com" }` but that didn't seem to work either.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, only `HTMLBody` property should be set. Setting `Body` overwrites HTML. Second, you probably want to replace some sections of your template (`firstname`). Pleas see full example below:

```
#replaceable parts marked using #
$body = @'
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Dear #firstname#,
                    Please visit <a href="www.google.com">here</a>

                    Kind Regards,
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <a href="#link1#">Click here</a>
                </td>
            </tr>only 
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
'@

$subject = 'Sample subject'

$parameters = @{
    firstname='MyName';
    link1='www.google.com'
}

#replace parts using dictionaryc as source
foreach ($pair in $parameters.GetEnumerator()) {
    $body = $body -replace "#$($pair.Key)#",$pair.Value
}

$ol = New-Object -comObject Outlook.Application
$mail = $ol.CreateItem(0)
$mail.Subject = $subject
#set HTML body only
$mail.HTMLBody = $body
$inspector = $mail.GetInspector
$inspector.Activate()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot! :)
I tested `$mail.HTMLbody` previously; but back then I was only using HTML in the place where I was trying to render the hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

I have this code (which I did not write) that I run in Windows PowerShell to create MS Outlook meeting invites and it works wonderfully. What I'd like to do though, is to be able to turn the "$meeting.Body" into an html body. I'd like to basically take any html code and add it into that "field" so that I can change the look and feel of the email body for the invitation.

Thank you very much for any help.

```
$meetingDate = Get-date "11/26/2021 5:00PM"
$ol = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$meeting = $ol.CreateItem('olAppointmentItem')
$meeting.Subject = 'This is your meeting invite'
$meeting.Body = 'Please join me in this meeting'
$meeting.Location = 'My Office'
$meeting.ReminderSet = $true
$meeting.Importance = 1
$meeting.MeetingStatus = 
[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlMeetingStatus]::olMeeting
$meeting.Recipients.Add('username@hotmail.com')
$meeting.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15
$meeting.Start = $meetingDate
$meeting.Duration = 30
$meeting.Send()
```